# IDR - File is not valid PE

Tags: windows, delphi, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I want to reverse old .exe file; I'm 90% sure it is Delphi (class names are being with 'T' => "TCommonDialog")

I can't load file into IDR (becouse it is not valid PE-executable?) jet still .exe works just fine and icon is showing just right.

I was trying to maniupulate header but every time I just corrupt .exe

Header with MZ:

```
00000000  4d 5a 00 01 01 00 00 00  08 00 10 00 ff ff 08 00  |MZ..............|
00000010  00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........@.......|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080
```

Further is longer header, but with NE; I was trying to change it to PE.
At this point I don't know what am I doing, I just mess with everything

```
00000000  4e 45 06 01 17 07 5a 00  00 00 00 00 0a 03 16 00  |NE....Z.........|
00000010  00 20 00 40 0e 00 01 00  00 00 16 00 16 00 0c 00  |. .@............|
00000020  0e 00 40 00 f0 00 9f 06  a9 06 c1 06 71 08 00 00  |..@.........q...|
00000030  0e 00 04 00 00 00 02 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 03  |................|
00000040  e4 36 cc 3d 10 1d cd 3d  e5 3a 47 3e 10 1d 47 3e  |.6.=...=.:G>..G>|
00000050  d3 3e 6f 3f 10 1d 70 3f  d6 42 96 3f 10 1d 97 3f  |.>o?..p?.B.?...?|
00000060  d9 46 20 3a 10 1d 21 3a  8f 4a 09 33 10 1d 0a 33  |.F :..!:.J.3...3|
00000070  cd 4d 99 30 10 1d 9a 30  df 50 1c 33 10 1d 1c 33  |.M.0...0.P.3...3|
00000080  17 54 7b 9a 10 1d 7b 9a  d3 5d 33 3c 10 1d 33 3c  |.T{...{..]3<..3<|
00000090  90 00 17 3a 50 1d 17 3a  57 04 c1 2f 50 1d c1 2f  |...:P..:W../P../|
000000a0  5b 07 2c 41 50 1d 2d 41  77 0b b9 66 50 1d ba 66  |[.,AP.-Aw..fP..f|
000000b0  f5 11 28 70 50 1d 28 70  1f 19 cc 22 50 1d cc 22  |..(pP.(p..."P.."|
000000c0  55 1b 00 6f 50 1d 00 6f  6c 22 84 7a 50 1d 85 7a  |U..oP..ol".zP..z|
000000d0  45 2a 31 51 50 1d 31 51  65 2f 8d 30 50 0d 8d 30  |E*1QP.1Qe/.0P..0|
000000e0  99 32 c6 1f 50 0d c6 1f  eb 34 5d 1f 59 0d 8c 2f  |.2..P....4].Y../|
000000f0  04 00 03 80 01 00 00 00  00 00 a9 61 30 00 10 1c  |...........a0...|
00000100  01 80 00 00 00 00 0e 80  01 00 00 00 00 00 d9 61  |...............a|
00000110  10 00 10 1c e4 03 00 00  00 00 0a 80 18 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 e9 61 30 00 30 1c  ed 03 00 00 00 00 19 62  |...a0.0........b|
00000130  10 11 30 1c f1 03 00 00  00 00 29 73 80 04 30 1c  |..0.......)s..0.|
00000140  fb 03 00 00 00 00 a9 77  40 00 30 1c 04 04 00 00  |.......w@.0.....|
00000150  00 00 e9 77 f0 04 30 1c  11 04 00 00 00 00 d9 7c  |...w..0........||
00000160  30 00 30 1c 1c 04 00 00  00 00 09 7d 80 00 30 1c  |0.0........}..0.|
00000170  25 04 00 00 00 00 89 7d  e0 00 30 1c 39 04 00 00  |%......}..0.9...|
00000180  00 00 69 7e 40 00 30 1c  48 04 00 00 00 00 a9 7e  |..i~@.0.H......~|
00000190  c0 01 30 1c 54 04 00 00  00 00 69 80 d0 05 30 1c  |..0.T.....i...0.|
000001a0  5b 04 00 00 00 00 39 86  50 00 30 1c 65 04 00 00  |[.....9.P.0.e...|
000001b0  00 00 89 86 60 00 30 1c  72 04 00 00 00 00 e9 86  |....`.0.r.......|
000001c0  50 00 30 1c 80 04 00 00  00 00 39 87 50 00 30 1c  |P.0.......9.P.0.|
000001d0  8f 04 00 00 00 00 89 87  40 00 30 1c 9c 04 00 00  |........@.0.....|
000001e0  00 00 c9 87 50 00 30 1c  a9 04 00 00 00 00 19 88  |....P.0.........|
000001f0  40 00 30 1c b6 04 00 00  00 00 59 88 50 00 30 1c  |@.0.......Y.P.0.|
00000200  c3 04 00 00 00 00 a9 88  50 00 30 1c d1 04 00 00  |........P.0.....|
00000210  00 00 f9 88 50 00 30 1c  de 04 00 00 00 00 49 89  |....P.0.......I.|
00000220  40 00 30 1c eb 04 00 00  00 00 89 89 70 01 30 1c  |@.0.........p.0.|
00000230  f8 04 00 00 00 00 f9 8a  90 00 30 1c 00 05 00 00  |..........0.....|
00000240  00 00 02 80 17 00 00 00  00 00 89 8b 10 00 30 1c  |..............0.|
00000250  05 05 00 00 00 00 99 8b  10 00 30 1c 0d 05 00 00  |..........0.....|
00000260  00 00 a9 8b 10 00 30 1c  18 05 00 00 00 00 b9 8b  |......0.........|
00000270  10 00 30 1c 1f 05 00 00  00 00 c9 8b 10 00 30 1c  |..0...........0.|
00000280  29 05 00 00 00 00 d9 8b  10 00 30 1c 33 05 00 00  |).........0.3...|
00000290  00 00 e9 8b 10 00 30 0c  3c 05 00 00 00 00 f9 8b  |......0.<.......|
000002a0  10 00 30 0c 45 05 00 00  00 00 09 8c 10 00 30 1c  |..0.E.........0.|
000002b0  4c 05 00 00 00 00 19 8c  10 00 30 1c 51 05 00 00  |L.........0.Q...|
000002c0  00 00 29 8c 10 00 30 1c  57 05 00 00 00 00 39 8c  |..)...0.W.....9.|
000002d0  10 00 30 1c 5c 05 00 00  00 00 49 8c 10 00 30 1c  |..0.\.....I...0.|
000002e0  63 05 00 00 00 00 59 8c  20 00 30 1c 68 05 00 00  |c.....Y. .0.h...|
000002f0  00 00 79 8c 20 00 30 1c  6f 05 00 00 00 00 99 8c  |..y. .0.o.......|
00000300  20 00 30 1c 74 05 00 00  00 00 b9 8c 20 00 30 1c  | .0.t....... .0.|
00000310  79 05 00 00 00 00 d9 8c  20 00 30 1c 7f 05 00 00  |y....... .0.....|
00000320  00 00 f9 8c 20 00 30 1c  88 05 00 00 00 00 19 8d  |.... .0.........|
00000330  20 00 30 1c 90 05 00 00  00 00 39 8d 20 00 30 1c  | .0.......9. .0.|
00000340  98 05 00 00 00 00 59 8d  20 00 30 1c 9e 05 00 00  |......Y. .0.....|
00000350  00 00 79 8d 20 00 30 1c  a6 05 00 00 00 00 01 80  |..y. .0.........|
00000360  06 00 00 00 00 00 99 8d  20 00 30 1c 01 80 00 00  |........ .0.....|
00000370  00 00 c9 8d 20 00 30 1c  02 80 00 00 00 00 f9 8d  |.... .0.........|
00000380  20 00 30 1c 03 80 00 00  00 00 29 8e 20 00 10 1c  | .0.......). ...|
00000390  04 80 00 00 00 00 59 8e  20 00 10 1c 05 80 00 00  |......Y. .......|
000003a0  00 00 89 8e 20 00 30 1c  06 80 00 00 00 00 0c 80  |.... .0.........|
000003b0  06 00 00 00 00 00 b9 8d  10 00 30 1c fb ff 00 00  |..........0.....|
000003c0  00 00 e9 8d 10 00 30 1c  fc ff 00 00 00 00 19 8e  |......0.........|
000003d0  10 00 30 1c fd ff 00 00  00 00 49 8e 10 00 30 1c  |..0.......I...0.|
000003e0  fe ff 00 00 00 00 79 8e  10 00 30 1c ff ff 00 00  |......y...0.....|
000003f0  00 00 a9 8e 10 00 30 1c  fa ff 00 00 00 00 06 80  |......0.........|
00000400  11 00 00 00 00 00 b9 8e  20 00 30 1c 01 8f 00 00  |........ .0.....|
00000410  00 00 d9 8e 20 00 30 1c  02 8f 00 00 00 00 f9 8e  |.... .0.........|
00000420  20 00 30 1c 03 8f 00 00  00 00 19 8f 20 00 30 1c  | .0......... .0.|
00000430  04 8f 00 00 00 00 39 8f  20 00 30 1c 05 8f 00 00  |......9. .0.....|
00000440  00 00 59 8f 20 00 30 1c  06 8f 00 00 00 00 79 8f  |..Y. .0.......y.|
00000450  20 00 30 1c 07 8f 00 00  00 00 99 8f 10 00 30 1c  | .0...........0.|
00000460  08 8f 00 00 00 00 a9 8f  10 00 30 1c 09 8f 00 00  |..........0.....|
00000470  00 00 b9 8f 20 00 30 1c  0a 8f 00 00 00 00 d9 8f  |.... .0.........|
00000480  20 00 30 1c 0b 8f 00 00  00 00 f9 8f 20 00 30 1c  | .0......... .0.|
00000490  f9 8f 00 00 00 00 19 90  20 00 30 1c fa 8f 00 00  |........ .0.....|
000004a0  00 00 39 90 10 00 30 1c  fb 8f 00 00 00 00 49 90  |..9...0.......I.|
000004b0  10 00 30 1c fd 8f 00 00  00 00 59 90 10 00 30 1c  |..0.......Y...0.|
000004c0  fe 8f 00 00 00 00 69 90  10 00 30 1c ff 8f 00 00  |......i...0.....|
000004d0
```

Comment: I made your hex-dumps a little more readable. This is the output of `hexdump -Cv`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the information provided by [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/format/exe/corion-ne.htm), you'll see that this is very likely an NE executable. These also start with `MZ`, but the rest is different.

Reading the bytes at offsets `0000000C` and `0000000D`, this is probably a Windows 3.x Protected Mode program. If it is made with Delphi, that can only have been Delphi 1, which did not produce PE executables, but 16 bit Windows executables instead.

Comment: @Iluvatar: it would be nice if you accepted my answer (click V-shaped icon under the score so it turns green).